# Подскажите, как сделать аккордион, расскрывающийся скроллом мыши. Примерно такой http://slinky.iclanzan.com/

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать аккордион, расскрывающийся скроллом мыши. Примерно такой http://slinky.iclanzan.com/

Comment: https://github.com/iclanzan/slinky

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLLeewW